# How do I fix this error in Django? <Corr: Item One>" needs to have a value for field "corr" before this many-to-many relationship can be used

Tags: python, django

I cannot figure out where this error is coming from. How do I solve this problem?

models.py:

```
class Corr(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    attr_x = models.ManyToManyField(Attr, related_name='attr_x')
    attr_y = models.ManyToManyField(Attr, related_name='attr_y')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

api.py:

```
@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
def corr_list(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        corr = Corr.objects.all()
        serializer = CorrSerializer(corr, many=True)
        return JsonResponse(serializer.data, safe=False)
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        serializer = CorrSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            # import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
            serializer.save() #<-- error here 
            return Response(serializer.validated_data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

What I have is a Corr model that can take two attr's, x and y, in a Many2Many relationship -- but when I call 'serialize.save()' I get the error above.

I'm not sure how to solve this. Serializer doesn't have/respect save_m2m(). Any help would be appreciated. I've tried a few different ways to knock this out in PDB but I always come back to the same error.

Help! How can I fix this?

Comment: can you show the data by printing it? means the data that is being passed in the serializer?

by using print(serializer )

Comment: print(serializer) gives me the model structure

Comment: tell me which is getting printed out. the serializer in the get req or the one in post? if the post one is getting printed then show the output of request.data

Comment: calling serializer.is_valid() returns False, so something else is going on. Request.data returns {u'name': u'Item One', u'attr_x': u'Age', u'attr_y':'Exp'}

Comment: so thats why you are getting a 404 bad request since the program is not going to the line save.

Comment: Hmm -- how can I move past that? Do I need to add a null=true and/or blank=true to the model?